# Codeception with phantomJS, fillField OK with real browser but KO when I run codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I'm a codeception beginner. 
From an acceptance test, I want fill and valid a login form. 
I use that :

```
public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
  $I->amOnPage('/'); //the url is good
  $I->fillField("//input[@name='Email']","foo"); //error here, the selector does not match 
  ...
}
```

But when I try the selector '//input[@name='Email']' in a real browser via an xpath plugin, the selector matches !

My question : I want debug my script, how can I get the code source of the page before the call of fillfield. I see here I can use "[_savePageSource](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#_savePageSource)" but when I use $I->getModule or $this->getModule in my function I get the error "getModule not found"

How can I use the _savePageSource method ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Don't you have the page source in the folder `tests/output` ?

Comment: When a test fails, in the output dir you should have the page's source saved (in its state when the particular error happened). Perhaps your page isn't fully loaded yet?